# Security login with Sonata and FosUser

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

If I follow this documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/security.html#user-list-customization

I have the error

> Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\DaoAuthenticationProvider::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface, instance of Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\UserManager given, called in C:\Users\chris\Desktop\projets\cav-php\var\cache\dev\ContainerQtsPCxG\getSecurity_Authentication_Provider_Dao_AdminService.php on line 15

I saw this was due to

```
providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_manager
```

Now If I change to

```
providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username
```

I'm being redirected in a infinite loop to my /admin/login page

Here is the rest of my security.yml

```
acl:
    connection: default
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager

    firewalls:
        # Disabling the security for the web debug toolbar, the profiler and Assetic.
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        # -> custom firewall for the admin area of the URL
        admin:
            pattern:            /admin(.*)
            context:            user
            form_login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                login_path:     /admin/login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     /admin/login_check
                failure_path:   null
            logout:
                path:           /admin/logout
                target:         /admin/login
            anonymous:          true

        main:
            pattern:      .*
            form-login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                login_path:     /login
                use_forward:    false
                check_path:     /login_check
                failure_path:   null
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    access_control:
        # The WDT has to be allowed to anonymous users to avoid requiring the login with the AJAX request
        - { path: ^/wdt/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/profiler/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        # AsseticBundle paths used when using the controller for assets
        - { path: ^/js/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/css/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        # URL of FOSUserBundle which need to be available to anonymous users
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/login_check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } # for the case of a failed login
        - { path: ^/user/new$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user/check-confirmation-email$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user/confirm/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user/confirmed$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user/request-reset-password$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user/send-resetting-email$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user/check-resetting-email$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user/reset-password/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        # Secured part of the site
        # This config requires being logged for the whole site and having the admin role for the admin part.
        # Change these rules to adapt them to your needs
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

    # Sonata "special" roles (ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN and ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN) are configurable
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    access_decision_manager:
        # strategy value can be: affirmative, unanimous or consensus
        strategy: unanimous
```

Comment: your security.yml looks ok , maybe is a routing problem , and also dont forget to clear your cach and cookies

Comment: Re-organizing all path seems to have solved the issue. I guess there is some kind of priority.